# Simple NN model for next word prediction

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I tried to made a simple model of Neural Networks model to make next word prediction.

I have a list of phrases and I split this list of phrases in a list of 3 words. E.g.

Input:

```
1. This is phrase number one.
2. This is phrase number two.
```

Result:

```
1. this is phrase
2. is phrase number
3. phrase number one
...
n. phrase number two
```

And this is for me X values. For Y values I put the 4-th word from every phrase.
E.g.

```
X[1]: this is phrase
y[1]: number
...
X[n]: is phrase number
y[n]: two
```

And, in finally a encode the X and Y with value of 0 and 1. E.g.

```
X[0]: 0 0 0 ... 1 0 1 0 ... 1 - maximum 3 of '1'
y[0]: 0 0 0 ... 1 0 0 0 ... 0 - maximum 1 of '1'
```

Where 1 in every vectors represent position of the word in my vocabulary.

And that is my data. I'm not very sure about if this is the best way to embedding. Exist another way more better?

Next, my model is like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=len(X_train[0]), kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=len(X_train[0]), kernel_initializer='uniform', activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(X_train[0]), input_dim=len(X_train[0]), kernel_initializer='uniform', activation ='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
```

But when I want to make a prediction I recived every time the same next word.

Recover code for next word prediction:

```
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    for i in range(0, len(X_test)):
    current_sentence = []
    pred_word = []
    for j in range(0, len(X_test[i])):
        if X_test[i][j] == 1:
            current_sentence.append(vocabulary[j])

    pred_word.append(vocabulary[list(y_pred[i]).index(max(y_pred[i]))])

    print("---------------\n")
    print("Current sentence: ", current_sentence)
    print("Next word prediction: ", pred_word)
```

Comment: whats your train set size? maybe your model has not learned enough yet. share the loss function scores.

Comment: X_train size is: 24 390. I run: `scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)` and I have `scores[0] = 0.00262085060021` and `scores[1] = 0.999780893326` And for pred I use `y_pred = model.predict(X_test)` where X_test size is 6 098, but my y_pred doesn't have just integer 0 and 1, have floats and from y_pred I search the index of max value. I added the recover code for next word pred in post.